# Upload by converting a multipart file to java.io.File

Tags: grails, file-upload, picasa

Currently, all I am doing is :

- Getting all the files :

  ```
  def itemPhotos = request.getMultiFileMap().item
  ```
- Transfering it to the server's tmp folder :

  ```
  for(itemPhoto in itemPhotos) {
      if(itemPhoto.getOriginalFilename().length() == 0)
          continue
      String path = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext()
              .getResource("/../tmp").getFile().toString() + File.separatorChar + itemPhoto.getOriginalFilename()
      itemPhoto.transferTo(new File(path))
      itemImages.add(new File(path))
  }
  ```
- And uploading them to the Picasa web album :

  ```
  if(!itemImages.isEmpty()) {
      def photoLinks = photoService.uploadImages(itemImages, itemInstance.id)
  }
  ```
- And deleting them after use :

  ```
  for(itemImage in itemImages)
      itemImage.delete()
  ```

Since, Picasa has method to upload files for `java.io.File` only. I have to first transfer the file to the local disk and then upload it. I know that when using multipart file upload, a temporary file is already created but I am transfering it for simplicity.

As I am going to upload this app and their will be a significant number of uploads at a time, how can I make this process less time consuming and also remove the burden of transfering & deleting the files?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

extend or replace the `picasa service` so it can pipe the files (as streams) from the request directly into the destination. I think a relatively simple implementation with `HttpBuilder` would do

Comment: Thanks, I will try using HttpBuilder.